# How to change initial state text in finite state machines with TikZ, automata library?

Tags: tikz-arrows

When a `\node` has the `initial` attribute a text appears saying "start". Can we change that text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `/tikz/initial text = <text>` keyval pair

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance = 2cm, on grid, auto, initial text = \textcolor{red}{INITIAL}]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \node[state, initial] (q_0) {$q_0$};
  \node[state] (q_1) [above right = of q_0] {$q_1$};
  \node[state] (q_2) [below right = of q_0] {$q_2$};
  \node[state, accepting](q_3) [below right = of q_1] {$q_3$};
  \path[->] (q_0) edge node {0} (q_1)
  edge node [swap] {1} (q_2)
  (q_1) edge node {1} (q_3)
  edge [loop above] node {0} ()
  (q_2) edge node [swap] {0} (q_3)
  edge [loop below] node {1} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]